# is there a standard Android Actionbar action icon for RECORD AUDIO

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-icons

I am developing an Android application that (among other features) allows the user to record audio.
i would like to use actionbar icons to allow the user easy access to STOP, PLAY, FAST FORWARD, and RECORD "actions". I have downloaded the Google supplied action bar icons but cannot see one for RECORD AUDIO. is there one?

Comment: i don't think there is, but that's ok. it's quite logical that many icons are missing. they can't present you with all possible icons :)

Comment: thats a fair answer, however it seems a bit odd they did every other AUDIO control icon, just not RECORD. I might just "plump" for using the same microphone icon used for voice search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ic_action_microphone.png in the core icons.
Download the entire package here:
https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html